# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using .dll file

Tags: java, audio, javasound, soundtouch

I am trying to use SoundTouch for a personal project (written in Java) as I think it is exactly what I need to modify audio clips (http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/). I am not building an Android app but have based a test program on the Android example provided on the github. Using the.dll file gives me a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. The exact error is as follows
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: SoundTouch.getVersionString()Ljava/lang/String;`

The 64 bit .dll is being found by the program but the methods can't be invoked.

- Is there an obvious solution to my issue?
- Can it be used by a Java program that isn't an Android app?

Comment: have you checked other answers to similar questions ? 
For instance these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror

Comment: @VeRo Yeah I have. I've seen this comment: `"then something is wrong with the library itself in the sense that Java is not able to map a native Java function in your application to its actual native counterpart."`
I wasn't sure how to go about solving this however. The .dll has clearly worked for other people